# How can I add a default text field if not mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html

New to JS here. I have a table with some mouseover functions with a tiny script to output the text to the right of the table.

I'm curious if there's a way I can set a default text once the user moves the mouse away. Right now, once you hover over the item, the output stays whatever the last mouseover was.

Since these are within tables i'm just showing the focused point of it.

```js
function writeText2(txt2) {
  document.getElementById("text_field2").innerHTML = txt2;
}
```

```html
    <div onmouseover="writeText2('the div works fine')">
      MOUSE OVER DIV
  </div>
  <td>
    <p id="text_field2">
      Prefer this to stay as default text if user moves mouse off the td above
    </p>
  </td>
  <td onmouseover="writeText2('the td works fine')">
      MOUSE OVER TD
  </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need the `mouseout` event.

While it's not good practice to use inline event listeners like this, since you've already started this way:

```js
function writeText2(txt2)
{
document.getElementById("text_field2").innerHTML=txt2; 
}
```

```html
    <p align="center" style="padding:0px 7px" onmouseover="writeText2('happy happy text text')" onmouseout="writeText2('My default text here')" id="text_field2">MOUSEOVERHERE</p>
```

(Note that I've changed the `<td>` to a `<p>` to get the snippet to work. And I've also added the id to the element, to show it working - you'll obviously have to adapt to your own use case, where the element you're targeting is different from the one the mouse enters and leaves.)

Comment: Oh i see. So there's no way to add it in the JS i take it? Was hoping i didn't have to write it for every single thing i'm using for 'mouseover'

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "there's no way to add it to the JS". What is "it"? And you absolutely can - and should! - use JS rather than HTML `onXXX` attributes to add event listeners. I only wrote it that way because I wanted to give you a quick illustration of the `mouseout` event, which seemed to be something you didn't know about.

Comment: I mean "it" as in the onmouseout being used in the script. Just so I don't have to copy and paste 'onmouseout' a bunch of different times. My 'onmouseover' is unique to each one so that's fine. But i'd like just a default text with the 'onmouseout'

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [onmouseenter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp) and [onmouseleave](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp)

```
<td align="center" style="padding:0px 7px" onmouseenter="writeText2('I moused over')" onmouseleave="writeText2('I left')">MOUSEOVERHERE</td>
```